# Can I automatically set up a SCRNAME in z/OS ISPF when I log in?

Tags: mainframe, zos, ispf

When I log into ISPF on z/OS 2.4, I usually immediately set up a custom SCRNAME. Since I do the same one every time, is it possible to set it to automatically set the SCRNAME every time I log in? How do I do that?

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with ZSTART,

Type 7;3 from the main screen,
Write 'l zstart' to check if already used,

if not found, you can add line by writing 'I'(insert) in command line left to the variable command,

In the new line that open write your command, for example to set the screen name to 'main' write:

```
zstart p ispf;scrname main
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify SCRNAME on the ISPF command.
ISPF PANEL(ISR@PRIM) SCRNAME(myprim)
The ISPF command above could then be put in a startup exec/clist that you invoke as part of logon

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned the use of the ISPF `ZSTART` profile variable is the best way to handle your need.

Check out https://github.com/lbdyck/zstart for an ISPF dialog that simplifies setting up and updating the `zstart` variable.